# error with ajax and json ..with php post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ok I am banging my head against my desk.
I am posting to a method in my php script and I am returning a json array

```
public function test()
    {
              return json_encode($this->runResults() );
            exit;
        }


    }
```

echo of above `(echo  json_encode($this->runResults() )` will give you this below

```
[
{"code":"123456","date_created":"2012-07-09","date_expires":null},{"code":"3453432","date_created":"2012-07-09","date_expires":null},
{"code":"3sdf324","date_created":"2012-07-09","date_expires":null},
{"code":"weewr22","date_created":"2012-07-09","date_expires":"2012-07-19"}
]
```

now in my javascript I have this

```
 $.ajax({

            url : 'test',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                data1: adataval,
                data2: bdataval
            },
            success : function(data) {

               alert(data.length);

            },
            error : function() {
            }
        });
```

and this alerts out in 1000s as it reads every single character..where as I was hoping that the length should have been 4. so then I change the above ajax to this

```
 $.ajax({

            url : 'test',
            type : 'POST',
datatype: 'json'
            data : {
                data1: adataval,
                data2: bdataval
            },
            success : function(data) {

               alert(data.length);

            },
            error : function() {
            }
        });
```

as you can see I added datatype: 'json'. but then I started getting
Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its actually `dataType` not `datatype`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this PHP Script

```
public function test()
{
    echo json_encode($this->runResults());
}
```

**Update :**

also in ajax method
use `dataType` not `datatype`

Answer (score 0):

`alert( $.parseJSON(data).length );`
Also, in your script, you should set the content-type to json: `header('Content-type: application/json');`